# Class with an ArrayList inside

Tags: java, class, oop, arraylist

I'm new to programming and i'd like some help.

I want to make a class that can add name,age and multiple phone numbers ( in some cases it will be 1, in others 4, etc...) and then show all the info.

I don't want to make it by creating another class for the ArrayList,
I'd like to do it all inside this class, I guess it's something simple to do but I can't figure this out and I'm not finding the solution I want.

what can I do about it? thx in advance, first time posting If I did something wrong please tell me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Athlete
{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList();

    public Athlete(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;

    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPhones()
    {
        return phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(ArrayList<String> phones)
    {
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Athlete{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", phones=" + phones + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the code you posted. "_I want to make a class that can add name,age and multiple phone numbers_" You already have all that in your code. A string for name, an int for age, and a list for numbers.

Comment: Your code looks fine, what is your problem?

Comment: Any errors you are running into when calling this class from anywhere?

Comment: The problem I see is in public @Override string toString() as he is trying to concatenate an array list to a string.

Comment: @RyanWilson Why would that be a problem? That's perfectly valid.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but aside from that, you shouldn't return mutable objects held by class. Currently we can have `athleteInstance.getPhones().add("whatever")`. Instead you should return copy of that list while logic which controls validity of number is in setter method like `void addNumber(String number){...}`.

Comment: @MaxVollmer You can concatenate an entire array list of strings to a string simply with + ??

Comment: You don't have to create an extra class for wrapping collections. You only do that if you need an extra behaviour related to that collection and is used in multiples points of your code.

In your case, it is fine to use the `ArrayList` directly.

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes.

Comment: @MaxVollmer Doesn't he need to use phones.toString() ??

Comment: @RyanWilson That happens automatically when using the + operator.

Comment: @MaxVollmer Interesting, been a while since I coded in Java. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an inner class for PhoneList and use that type instead of directly working with the ArrayList.

```
public class Athlete
{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private PhoneList phoneList;

    public Athlete(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        phoneList = new PhoneList();

    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // Maybe just return the toString (or a read only list)
    public PhoneList getPhones()
    {
        return phoneList;
    }

    publicvoid addPhone(String phone)
    {
        phoneList.add(phone);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Athlete{" + "name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", phones=" + phoneList + '}';
    }

    private class PhoneList
    {
        private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        private void add(String phone)
        {
            list.add(phone);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(32);

            for (String ph : list)
            {
                b.append(ph + "\n"); // Or something
            }

            return b.toString();
        }
    }

}
```